# Make new tr with td based on information from external server/API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to make new tr and td elements to generate a score-table in JavaScript from this server: https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021

I have a hard time understanding how to get the information from the website into a function that will display it on my website. Is something wrong or does it need something more?

Thanks

```
function getStryktipset() {
    return fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021')
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data){
            return data.matches[0].teams
        })
}

function generate_tablerows() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");

        var cellText = document.createTextNode();
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        document.getElementsById("table").appendChild(row);
    }
}

function start(){
    getStryktipset().then(generate_tablerows)
}
```

How It should look from the data I have:
[Example-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB3mY.png)

I already have the table-headers but nothing else.

Comment: That url returns an array of objects for matches. What data do you want to show in the table. Can you give an example?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I updated my code with a picture to see the how the result should look like.

Comment: Beware that with your current For Loop structure in `generate_tablerows` you only ever end up making 1 `tr` because you overwrite the `row` variable 13 times before you move on to create the `td`s that are supposed to go in there. Not sure if that's intended behaviour or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example for you to try.

The result being returned by https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021 is already in JSON format so you can use it just like a JavaScript object.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  start();
});

function start() {
  getStryktipset().then(drawTable);
}

function getStryktipset() {
  return fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}

function drawTable(result) {
  const matches = result.matches;
  const table = document.createElement('table');
 
  // table headers
  const headers = document.createElement('tr');
  ['Rad:', 'Lag:', '1', 'X', '2'].forEach(header => {
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerText = header;
    headers.appendChild(th);
  });
  table.appendChild(headers);

  //table content
  matches.forEach(match => {
    // td for match number
    const matchNumber = document.createElement('td');
    matchNumber.textContent = match.matchNumber;

    // td for teams
    const teams = document.createElement('td');
    teams.textContent = `${match.teams['1'].name} -VS- ${match.teams['2'].name}`;

    // td for match result
    const outCome1 = document.createElement('td');
    if (match.matchInfo.outcome === '1') {
      outCome1.innerHTML = '&#10003';
    }

    const outComeX = document.createElement('td');
    if (match.matchInfo.outcome === 'X') {
      outComeX.innerHTML = '&#10003';
    }

    const outCome2 = document.createElement('td');
    if (match.matchInfo.outcome === '2') {
      outCome2.innerHTML = '&#10003';
    }

    // append table data to row.
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.appendChild(matchNumber);
    row.appendChild(teams);
    row.appendChild(outCome1);
    row.appendChild(outComeX);
    row.appendChild(outCome2);

    // then append row to table.
    table.appendChild(row);
  });

  // finally, append the table to the target HTML tag.
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save time creating table rows and cells using `Table.insertRow()` and `Row.insertCell()`

```js
function getStryktipset() {
  return fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}

getStryktipset().then(generate_tablerows);

function createHeadRow(table) {
  const columns = ['Rad:', 'Lag:', '1', 'X', '2'],
    headRow = table.insertRow();

  columns.forEach(function(col) {
    const cell = document.createElement('th');
    cell.textContent = col;
    headRow.appendChild(cell)
  });
}

function createMatchRows(table, matches) {
  const outcomes = ['1', 'X', '2'];

  matches.forEach(function(m) {
    const row = table.insertRow(),
      teamText = [m.teams[1].name, m.teams[2].name].join(' - '),
      // create array for content of each cell
      content = [m.matchNumber, teamText];
    // add the outcomes content pushing either the CHECK or empty string
    outcomes.forEach(function(v) {
      content.push(v === m.matchInfo.outcome ? '&#10003' : '')
    });
    // looop over the content array and create a cell for each input
    content.forEach(function(v,i) {
      const cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = v;
      if(i > 1){
        cell.className='match-outcome';
      }      
    });
  });

}

function generate_tablerows(data) {
  const table = document.querySelector('#matches');
  createHeadRow(table);
  createMatchRows(table, data.matches);
}
```

```css
th{min-width: 30px}
td.match-outcome {text-align:center}
```

```html
<table id="matches" border="1"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified a lot using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). This is my suggestion:

```js
const fetchData = async() => (await fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2021')).json();

fetchData()
  .then(data => {
    var rows = '<tr><th>Rad:</th><th>Lag:</th><th>1</th><th>X</th><th>2</th></tr>';
    data.matches.forEach(e => {
      rows += `<tr>
<td>${e.matchNumber}</td>
<td>${e.teams[1].name} - ${e.teams[2].name}</td>
<td class="outcome">${e.matchInfo.outcome === '1' ? '&#10003' : ''}</td>
<td class="outcome">${e.matchInfo.outcome === 'X' ? '&#10003' : ''}</td>
<td class="outcome">${e.matchInfo.outcome === '2' ? '&#10003' : ''}</td>
</tr>`;
    });
    grid.innerHTML = rows;
  });
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.outcome {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="grid"></table>
```